# Fourier Series Summation in Python

Tags: python

I'm attempting to graph a Fourier series summation in Python. Thus far, I have this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from sympy import *
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = Symbol('n')
x = Symbol('x')

L_1 = -1
L_2 = 1
f = -x

a_0 = (1 / L_2) * integrate(f, (x, L_1, L_2))
a_n = (1 / L_2) * integrate(f * cos(n * pi * x / L_2), (x, L_1, L_2))
b_n = (1 / L_2) * integrate(f * sin(n * pi * x / L_2), (x, L_1, L_2))

F = (a_0 / 2) + mpmath.fsum((a_n * cos(n * pi * x / L_2)) + (b_n * sin(n * pi * x / L_2)), [0, 20])
print(F)
```

However, fsum is throwing up an error:

```
F = (a_0 / 2) + mpmath.fsum((a_n * cos(n * pi * x / L_2)) + (b_n * sin(n * pi * x / L_2)), [0, 20])
File "C:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\sympy\mpmath\ctx_mp_python.py", line 831, in fsum
for term in terms:
TypeError: 'Mul' object is not iterable
```

I'm not clear on what a Mul object is, or what my issue actually is. Does someone have any pointers for getting this summation working? Like I said, the end goal is to plug in some values for x and sum over n iterations, in this case 20.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about why its throwing Mul object error, the error means the object is single item and not iterable.

Regarding the method you are trying to use mpmath.fsum, the signature is not matching with the [documentation](http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/general.html#fsum).

```
mpmath.fsum(terms, absolute=False, squared=False)
```

The method which you are using, seems match with [nsum](http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/calculus/sums_limits.html#mpmath.nsum).

```
mpmath.nsum(ctx, f, *intervals, **options)
```

If you want to implement fourier transform in python, you can check the implementation [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Python) using python and numpy.

Answer (score 0):

SymPy 1.0 has been included with `fourier_series` function that lets you compute Fourier Series of a function. Docs can be found [here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/fourier.html).

eg.

```
>>> f = fourier_series(-x, (x, -1, 1))
>>> f.truncate(5)
-2*sin(pi*x)/pi + sin(2*pi*x)/pi - 2*sin(3*pi*x)/(3*pi)
```